# What is my capacitance?

Tags: voltage, capacitance, 12v, 5v

I have a current measurement of 300mA on an MCU evaluation board. If my power supply is 19V or 12V what capacitance do I need to use in order to limit the voltage fall to 5V?

Comment: Your question is really not clear.  Either you don't really understand the basics, or else you've left a LOT out of your question.

Comment: Capacitance won't do it so the answer is ... none.

Comment: For how long time?

Answer (score 4):

You need a voltage regulator, not a capacitor.  A switch-mode type regulator would be best, particularly when using a 19 volt power supply, to minimize the power lost as heat in the regulator.